# Insert data into external MSSQL database through Yii Framework

Tags: database, insert, yii, external

I'm using Yii Framework to create my project. I need to export some data from MySQL (my project) to an external Microsoft SQL server which is on the same network.

Basically, the user needs to click on a button (which will do the export-insert) in my view and the results should be displayed - Success (if the query has been successful) or Failure (if something went wrong).
The results part is quite easy as I'll be using 'setFlash' to display the appropriate message but I want to know how to insert data into an external database through Yii.

Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I agree with @SuVeRa on the first part of defining two `db` instances in the `config.php` but i don't think the **sql Commands** part is necessary (Plus i hate writing sql :D )

**Instead you can do:**

```
class SomeModel extends CActiveRecord 
{
  ...
  // Override the getDbConnection() function to use the ms sql db connection
  public function getDbConnection()
  {
     return Yii::app()->ms_sql_db_connection; // The name of the connection in config.php
  }

  public function transfer()
  {
    // Here you can do all the transferring logic using normal Yii Active Record functions
  }
}
```

Check out the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getDbConnection-detail) on `getDbConnection()`.